# Getting Error with MainActivity Android Studio

Tags: android

i am beginner, and struggling badly to debug. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Viewpager has stopped. this is error on emulator and app is not running.

Comment: Add your full crash log in the question, and the code of the Main Activity

Comment: you shouldn't put java file in the `androidTest` path, you should create the `MainActivity` in the `main/java`

Comment: This has solved my problem ... Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.home.viewpager.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write whole path your Activity class.

```
android:name="com.example.home.viewpager.MainActivity"
```